# Why doesn't my page response do mouse clicks?

Tags: jquery

I have posted my example here

http://jsfiddle.net/abt5w/1/

HTML:

```
<p class='para'>
<div class='test'>Hello</div>
</p>
```

JS:

```
 $('.test').on('click', function(e) {
     alert('clicked');
 });
$('.para').append("<div class='test'>Hello 2</div>");
```

The standard 'Hello' responds to mouse clicks.  However when I append 'Hello 2' that text does not respond to a mouse click even though they should both be triggered by the same code.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change it to

```
$('.para').on("click",".test",function(e) {
     alert('clicked');
 });
```

When you use delegated event, the event handler is attached only to the parent element. Jquery does not attach more event handlers for descendant elements . That's another benefit

> When a selector is provided, the event handler is referred to as
>   delegated. The handler is not called when the event occurs directly on
>   the bound element, but only for descendants (inner elements) that
>   match the selector. jQuery bubbles the event from the event target up
>   to the element where the handler is attached (i.e., innermost to
>   outermost element) and runs the handler for any elements along that
>   path matching the selector.
>
> In addition to their ability to handle events on descendant elements
>   not yet created, another advantage of delegated events is their
>   potential for much lower overhead when many elements must be
>   monitored.On a data table with 1,000 rows in its tbody, this example attaches a handler to 1,000 elements:

```
 $("#dataTable tbody tr").on("click", function(event){  
      alert($(this).text()); 
   });
```

> A delegated-events approach attaches an
>   event handler to only one element, the tbody, and the event only needs
>   to bubble up one level (from the clicked tr to tbody):
>
> ```
> $("#dataTable tbody").on("click", "tr", function(event){  
>  alert($(this).text()); 
> });
> ```

From [$.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

You may attach the delegated event handler to the `document` in case you need to monitor all the `.test`

```
$(document).on("click",".test",function(e) {
     alert('clicked');
 });
```

But as the document states, the event has to bubble up more levels. Consider attaching to the document or only the `.para`

Answer (score 2):

That's because you need to subscribe to the click event in a *lively* manner, using the `.on()` function:

```
$('.para').on('click', '.test', function(e) {
     alert('clicked');
});
```

Now jQuery will execute the click handler even for DOM elements that didn't yet exist at the moment you called the .on function to subscribe.

Comment: You think that jquery attaches more event handlers?

Comment: Actually, jquery does not listen for DOM elements that match the selector and automatically attach the .click event to them

Comment: i think this won't work. becuaus he is appending the to the end of a `.para`.

Answer (score 0):

The way you have written your code, this will work;

```
 $(document).on('click', 'div.test', function(e) {
     alert('clicked');
 });
```

However, you can try also like this;

```
<div id="container">
    <p class='para'>
        <div class='test'>Hello</div>
    </p>    
</div>
```

and then;

```
 $('#container').on('click', 'div.test', function(e) {
     alert('clicked');
 });
$('.para').append("<div class='test'>Hello 2</div>");
```